# How to iterate over a generic vector

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, vector, iterator

I've always found C++ templates inscrutable, and C++ error messages more so. I want to understand it, rather than always feeling confused. Here's the latest bizarre experience:

```
error: conversion from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to non-scalar type ‘std::vector<int>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >}’ requested
```

This doozy comes from the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void printVector(const vector<T>& v) {
    for (typename vector<T>::iterator iter = v.begin; iter != v.end; iter++) {
        cout << *iter << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
    printVector(v);
    return 0;
}
```

It has no problem iterating over the vector if I use a C++11 range-based loop. I want to learn how to do it using iterators.

Can someone explain what the error means and how to fix it?

It would also be wonderful if I could get a recommendation of a book that explains templates well.

Comment: You need `begin()` and `end()`. Voting to close as trivial typo.

Comment: When writing template code, it is often (not always) a good idea to write it first non-template for a single concrete case.  Then, copy/paste it and make it a template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the error message carefully. It says you're trying to convert a function to iterator. You should call them by adding `()`.

Change

```
for (typename vector<T>::iterator iter = v.begin; iter != v.end; iter++) {
```

to

```
for (typename vector<T>::iterator iter = v.begin(); iter != v.end(); iter++) {
                                                ~~               ~~
```

For C++ books, [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the parentheses from `begin` and `end` and since you're passing the vector by const reference you'll need a `const_iterator`.

```
template <typename T>
void printVector(const vector<T>& v) {
    for (typename vector<T>::const_iterator iter = v.begin(); iter != v.end(); iter++) {
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^               ^^                ^^
        cout << *iter << endl;
    }
}
```

Better yet use a ranged base for:

```
template <typename T>
void printVector(const vector<T>& v) {
    for(auto &&e : v) {
        cout << e << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the advantage of using `auto &&e` over `auto e`?

Comment: @MichaelAnderson It's useful for proxies (e.g., `std::vector<bool>`).

Comment: Why is the bitwise `&&` being used over the standard `&`? I notice in my personal example I'm not getting any difference.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector<T>::begin` and `::end` are functions; you need to call them:

```
for (typename vector<T>::iterator iter = v.begin(); iter != v.end(); iter++) {
//                                              ^^               ^^
    cout << *iter << endl;
}
```

Additionally, you are trying to convert a `const` iterator to a non-`const` one. You need to use `vector<T>::const_iterator`, or, better yet, `auto`.